# Creating applications for all platforms on Ubuntu

Tags: tidesdk

Is it possible to use TiedSDK under Ubuntu(12.10) to create Windows and Mac apps?
And if it is possible how should I use the other SDKs(Win|OSx)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no way to cross compile / generate installers for other platforms. If you want installers for windows .. you need to be running on a windows system. You can get a virtual machine with any windows operating system.

Comment: where can I get support on a issue that is not documented ? (Sorry for the question but saw you in GitHub as TideSDK contributor) ty

Comment: If you are getting any issue with TideSDK platform, please report that   here: https://github.com/TideSDK/TideSDK/issues
You can also try contacting on our google mail group or IRC (irc.freenode.net -- #tidesdk)
thanks